# Each method deprecated Automapper upgrade

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am using Automapper in my .NET Application.  I am currently using version 3.3.0 and I have just upgraded the Nuget package to latest version 7.1.0.  I have fixed most of the Breaking changes.

I am not sure on the correct fix for the below:

This was the method in Automapper 3.0.0

```
public static void Each<T>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> items, System.Action<T> action)

    Member of AutoMapper.EnumerableExtensions
```

I was using it in my code like below:

```
           customer.CustomerQuerys.Each(

                l => l.OnProductChanged += (sender, args) =>

                {

                    switch (args.Result)

                    {

                        case DataChangedEventFlags.ProductChanged:

                            messages.Add("ProductChanged " + ((CustomerCoreData)sender).ProductName);

                            break;

                    }

                });
```

CustomerQuerys is a ReadOnlyCollection on the customer object

Answer (score -1):

Be careful of what you use from a 3rd party library. That method has clearly nothing to do with AutoMapper and most have been intented for internal use. Also consider readabilty of your code. Why not just have a foreach loop like below. Takes more space, but sometimes easier to read.

```
public void DoStuff()
{
   foreach(var customer in customer.CustomerQuerys)
   {
      customer.OnProductChanged += HandleProductChanged;
   }
}

private void HandleProductChanged(object sender, DataChangedEvent args)
{
   switch (args.Result)
   {
       case DataChangedEventFlags.ProductChanged:
          messages.Add("ProductChanged " + ((CustomerCoreData)sender).ProductName);
          break;
   }
}
```

If you really want one you can create your own:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```